# Не могу понять,в чём ошибка

Tags: java

Только начал изучать принципы "ООП".
Хотел сделать программу, которая считывает символы, переводит их в смайликовый формат.

Столкнулся с проблемой не понимания.

Что именно мне не понятно:

Мне не ясно почему, вызывая метод "getstr", возвращается та же строка что я ввёл через сканер, а не та что должна была(по-идее) перекодироваться.

```java
package MySense;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainString {
    Wrap wla;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ob = s.nextLine();
        char[] array1 = new char[ob.length()];
        Wrap wlast = new Wrap(ob);
        System.out.println(wlast.getStr());
    }

    public void write(int y) {
        char[] array1 = new char[100];
        char[] r = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'щ', 'Ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', ' '};
        char[] t = {'@', '&', '#', '^', ':', '(', ')', '໒', '◐', '✪', '卍', '♣', '☯', '§', '۞', '♖', 'ஜ', '☭', '⚜', '♜', '⊒', '⊊', 'ℓ', 'ঐ', '௹', '௵', 'ֆ', '∏', 'Ҩ', '❧', '≈', '▩', '๑', ' '};
        wla.replace(r[y], t[y]);
        y++;
        array1[y] = t[y];
    }
}
```

```java
package MySense;

public class Wrap {
    MainString mainString;
    private String str;

    public Wrap(String ob) {
        this.str = ob;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    ;

    public String replace(char oldChae, char NewChar) {
        String f;
        char[] array = new char[str.length()];
        str.getChars(0, str.length(), array, 0);
        for (int yoyo = 0; yoyo < 100; yoyo--) {
            for (int yo = 0; yo < 33; yo++) {
                if (array[yoyo] == oldChae) {
                    array[yoyo] = NewChar;
                    mainString.write(yo);
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код надо текстом. И поясните в чем у вас проблема

Answer (score 3):

***Первая ошибка***:
Метод write напрямую относится к классу Wrap, поэтому он должен быть там.
***Замечание***:
Вы используете getChars(,,,) без надобности, засунуть String в char массив, если размерность массива должна быть равна размерности строки, можно следующим способом:

```
char[] c = str.toCharArray();
```

***Второе замечание***:
Массивы r и t не изменяются - значит они должны быть константами(final)(объявите в начале класса Wrap). А если они используются в статических методах - то  они должны быть статическими константами(final static):

```
final static char[] r = {...};
final static char[] t = {...};
```

***Третье замечание***:
Строка f в методе replace вообще не использовалась.
***Вторая ошибка***:
В методе replace для перечисления всех элементов массива вы используете следующую запись:

```
for (int yoyo = 0; yoyo < 100; yoyo--) {
```

То есть вы обрабатываете только первый элемент массива, а потом должно выдавать ошибку "выход за размерность массива"(так как yoyo теперь отрицательно). Хорошо, сделали yoyo++. Теперь нужно заменить 100 на array.length, так как мы хотим пройтись по всему массиву. Предлагаю следующий вариант:

```
for (int yoyo = 0; yoyo < array.length; yoyo++) {
```

33 также можно заменить на r.length или t.length.
***Третья ошибка***: 
Вы не изменяете нигде значение str после конструктора. Поэтому getStr и возвращает значение, заданное в конструкторе.

***Вы используете метод replace для замены символа old на new, так? Зачем постоянно перебирать массив, если вы в конце концов заменяете ВСЕ символы? Предлагаю следующий вариант класса Wrap(метода replace(теперь convert) в частности)***:

```
class Wrap {
    final public static char[] oldSymbols = {'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'щ', 'Ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', ' '};
    final public static char[] newSymbols = {'@', '&', '#', '^', ':', '(', ')', '໒', '◐', '✪', '卍', '♣', '☯', '§', '۞', '♖', 'ஜ', '☭', '⚜', '♜', '⊒', '⊊', 'ℓ', 'ঐ', '௹', '௵', 'ֆ', '∏', 'Ҩ', '❧', '≈', '▩', '๑', ' '};

    public static String convert(String oldS) {
        char[] newS = new char[oldS.length()];

        boolean haveSymbol = false;
        for(int o = 0; o < oldS.length(); o++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < oldSymbols.length; i++) {
                if(oldSymbols[i] == oldS.charAt(o)) {
                    newS[o] = newSymbols[i];
                    haveSymbol = true;
                }
            }
            if(haveSymbol) {
                haveSymbol = false;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("В строке " + oldS + ", переданной в качестве аргумента, есть отсутствующий(е) в массиве oldSymbols символ(ы). Первый: " + oldS.charAt(o));
            }
        }
        return new String(newS);
    }
}
```

Проверка:

```
System.out.println(Wrap.convert("пррривет"));
```

Вывод:

> ஜ☭☭☭✪#(♜

Answer (score 1):

Вы же выводите на печать `wlast.getStr()`. А метод `getStr()` возвращает исходную строку. Остальные методы replace() и write() просто не используются. 
Да и вообще очень уж заморочено у вас все. Я бы сделала проще:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ob = s.nextLine();
        Wrap wlast = new Wrap();
        System.out.println(wlast.coding(ob));
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Wrap {
    public String coding(String str) {
        String r = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя";
        String t = "@&#^:()໒◐✪卍♣☯§۞♖ஜ☭⚜♜⊒⊊ℓঐ௹௵ֆ∏Ҩ❧≈▩๑";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (r.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                res.append(t.charAt(r.indexOf(str.charAt(i))));
            } else {
                res.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
}
```

**Результат:**

`велосипед`

`#(☯♖⚜✪ஜ(:`

Comment: https://ideone.com/sYHZxu

Comment: А зачем вы принимаете в конструктор строку, в последствии никак ее не используя? Достаточно просто убрать класс Wrap и сделать метод coding статическим.

Comment: Да и зачем вас использовать StringBuilder, когда вы точно знаете размерность будущей строки - используйте char[].

Comment: Понятно, что проще все обработать статическим методом. Но ТС начал изучать принципы "ООП". И, вероятно, ему нужен все-таки отдельный класс. По поводу char[]. Вы с вашим массивом используете два цикла, а я со строкой лишь один.

Comment: А с конструктором да. Вы правы, конечно. Он лишний.

Comment: Большое Спасибо всем за помощь.
Я ещё только  учусь, но я верю,что алгоритмическое мышление вопрос времени